# Tkinter, enclosing_frame.grid_propogate(0) to prevent resizing also prevents updating label text

Tags: python, tkinter, resize

This is pretty simple.

I have a label along the bottom of my app. As a user scrolls through a treeview, the content of that label changes. Sometimes, the content is *multiple lines long*.

Previously, the label would grow/shsrink to accommodate content. I didn't like this, so I wrapped the label in a frame, gave said frame a fixed height, and set `grid_propagate(0)`. It looks great, but now my text has disappeared.

How can I give the label a fixed size and retain the ability to update its text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give your label a fixed `width`

```
lbl1 = Label(root, text = "Stuff....", width = 10)
lbl1.configure(text = "Another longer stuff....")
```

if you give it a fixed `width` value, it won't expand automatically.

**Update**

Here's what I've tried and worked.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
canv = Canvas(root,height=17)
canv.grid_propagate(0)
lbl1 = Label(canv,text="First line\nSecond Line")
lbl1.grid(column=0,row=0)
canv.grid(column=0,row=0)
root.mainloop()
```

I wrapped the label in a canvas instead of a frame and it worked (only the text "First line" appears). Play around with the `height` value of the canvas.

Comment: Yes, but you can't give a height value at all. The issue here is content that is multiple lines long.

Comment: Ok, wait, updating answer

Comment: Sweet. I look forward to it :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather then a Label use a Text inside the Frame and add a vertical scrollbar with the Text.  Pack both the Text and the Scrollbar in the Frame, using examples online, and connect them up.  Once you cancel propagate for the Frame it won't resize.  You can then set the Frame to whatever size you want, even set the Text for a specific number of lines and columns of text before you cancel propagate for the Frame, and then you can display as much text as you want at the bottom allowing the user to scroll through if it is too big.